# figure out scrollbar width to stop content from moving

Tags: jquery, width, scrollbar, panel

I have a hidden panel that when you click on a grey box the panel loads in from the right. However I wanted to make it so that once the panel was visible it was only possible to scroll within the panel and not the body content as well.

I have this all working fine, however to achieve this the scroll bar disappears from the main content, which moves the content to the right slightly and then reappears on the sliding panel.

You can see a live version of the problem [here](http://hutchcreative.co.uk/test/). If you scroll to the bottom and click on the grey box it will activate and slide in the panel.

I also have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x5Bhf/1/) but the problem doesn't actually get reproduced in here. I think it could be because its in a frame.

Im thinking the best way to solve this is to figure out the width of the scroll bar and make sure the content in the main body doesn't move across. I found this code that is supposed to figure out the width of the scrollbar but Im not sure how to incorporate it into my script.

Here is my script.

```
$('#sauceThumb').click(function () {

$('#mainContent').addClass('blur');
$('#sauceDet').animate({
    right: "0"
}, 700, 'linear');
var scrollPos = {
    top  : self.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft,
    left : self.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop  || document.body.scrollTop
};
$('body, html').data('scroll', scrollPos).css('overflow', 'hidden');
window.scrollTo(scrollPos.top, scrollPos.left);
});
$('.close, #cover').click(function () {
    $('#sauceDet').animate({
        right: "-9999px"
    }, 1500, 'linear');
    $('#mainContent').removeClass('blur');
    $('#cover').fadeOut(200);
    var pos = $('body, html').css('overflow', 'auto').data('scroll');
    window.scrollTo(pos.top, pos.left);
});

function getScrollBarWidth () {
    var inner = document.createElement('p');
    inner.style.width = "100%";
    inner.style.height = "200px";

    var outer = document.createElement('div');
    outer.style.position = "absolute";
    outer.style.top = "0px";
    outer.style.left = "0px";
    outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
    outer.style.width = "200px";
    outer.style.height = "150px";
    outer.style.overflow = "hidden";
    outer.appendChild (inner);

    document.body.appendChild (outer);
    var w1 = inner.offsetWidth;
    outer.style.overflow = 'scroll';
    var w2 = inner.offsetWidth;
    if (w1 == w2) w2 = outer.clientWidth;

    document.body.removeChild (outer);

    return (w1 - w2);
};
```

Comment: Added text to the fiddle to see the effect there - http://jsfiddle.net/x5Bhf/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do this add and remove the width from the parent container of your underlying content:

```
var scrollbarWidth = parseInt(getScrollBarWidth (),10); //get width of scroll bars, assume its constant
$('#sauceThumb').click(function () {
    if($('#sauceDet').css("right") === "-9999px") // don't do anything if panel is already being shown
    {    
        $('#mainContent').addClass('blur');
        $('#sauceDet').animate({
        right: "0"
        }, 700, 'linear');
        var scrollPos = {
        top  : self.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft,
        left : self.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop  || document.body.scrollTop
        };
        $('body, html').data('scroll', scrollPos).css('overflow', 'hidden');
        $('body').css('margin-right',parseInt($('body').css('margin-right'),10) + scrollbarWidth + 'px'); // add width to body margin
        window.scrollTo(scrollPos.top, scrollPos.left);
    }    
});
$('.close, #cover').click(function () 
{
    $('#sauceDet').animate({
        right: "-9999px"
    }, 1500, 'linear');
    $('#mainContent').removeClass('blur');
    $('#cover').fadeOut(200);
    var pos = $('body, html').css('overflow', 'auto').data('scroll');
    $('body').css('margin-right',parseInt($('body').css('margin-right'),10) - scrollbarWidth + 'px'); // remove width from body margin
    window.scrollTo(pos.top, pos.left);
});

function getScrollBarWidth () {
    var inner = document.createElement('p');
    inner.style.width = "100%";
    inner.style.height = "200px";
    var outer = document.createElement('div');
    outer.style.position = "absolute";
    outer.style.top = "0px";
    outer.style.left = "0px";
    outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
    outer.style.width = "200px";
    outer.style.height = "150px";
    outer.style.overflow = "hidden";
    outer.appendChild (inner);
    document.body.appendChild (outer);
    var w1 = inner.offsetWidth;
    outer.style.overflow = 'scroll';
    var w2 = inner.offsetWidth;
    if (w1 == w2) w2 = outer.clientWidth;
    document.body.removeChild (outer);
    return (w1 - w2);
};
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/x5Bhf/6/

Note that the fiddle content does move vertically when your panel appears because the height of the body changes, you may or may not have to compensate for this in your original code.

**EDIT** Code sample modified to handle invalid clicks

Comment: Thank you for that, its almost there! However once I open and close a panel the body is given a horizontal scroll. Is there way to stop that? It also gradually moves the content towards the right every time you open and close a panel.

Comment: This does not happen in the fiddle I have included so it might be caused by some other part of the code or different dimensions in your code, if you are able to reproduce the effect in the fiddle then I could possibly explain how you can remove it.

Comment: It is currently in the fiddle. If you keep opening and closing the panel you can see the text start to reposition.

Comment: The text was moving because the click handler function was being activated when you clicked on the div even when the panel was already displayed, added a check for that. Although I don't understand what you mean by horizontal scroll to the body. Also be aware that you will need to check for cases when the underlying content does not have scroll bars. Edited to prevent action when the animation is being performed as well.

Comment: If you test it out on this test link http://hutchcreative.co.uk/v2/ you can see the horizontal scrollbar being added. Scroll down to one of the 3 square panels. Here is a fiddle jsfiddle.net/x5Bhf/8/ you can see if you click the text to open and close the panel it adds a scroll bar

Comment: On that page you are adding three click handler to elements with class "close" and id "cover" you are using the above code to fix the body margin three times, you only need to fix it once so remove the line commented with "remove with from body margin" from two of the three handlers. Alternatively a more optimal solution would be to combine the three handler functions into a single one.